# making maps using Qt

Tags: postgis, qt

D maps using Openstreetmap data with the help of Qt. I need to use Qt specifically as other components in the software have objects that integrate into the map using Qt. How should I proceed? Can I parse postgis data to construct maps using Qt? Are there some tutorials?

Answer (score 5):

Other option is [QGIS](http://qgis.org). It offers [a robust API](http://doc.qgis.org/api/) in C++, with Python bindings ([PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/index.html)). You are not required to use the QGIS GUI, allowing you to build your own app with QGIS components embedded in your Qt app.

Check the [development docs](http://www.qgis.org/en/community/development.html), and the [PyQGIS Cookbook](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/) for more info on [creating standalone Python-based apps](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/intro.html#python-applications).

**Edit**: More info on building available on QGIS Wiki...
[Quantum GIS Desktop - Development - QGIS Issue Tracking](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Development)
[Quantum GIS Desktop - Writing custom Applications with QGIS API](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Writing_custom_Applications_with_QGIS_API)

Comment: Word of caution, it is GPL code

Comment: Word of encouragement, it is GPL code :)

Comment: hahahahaha or that of course :)

Answer (score 4):

Consider looking to merkaator. It is an editor for openstreetmap using qt: http://merkaartor.be/ and marble: http://edu.kde.org/marble/ which has a qt mapping widget

Comment: Thanks for posting the links to those. They both look like interesting, useful and active projects. I was searching for a decent OSM editor for Mac, and Merkaartor seems a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Qt has its own mapping module, QtLocation, supporting both raster and vector tiles. Perhaps you can make use of that one